# Guice injectMembers method

Tags: guice

I understand the benefits of using constructor injection over setter injection but in some cases I have to stick with setter-based injection only.

My question is how to inject members of all the setter-based injection classes using `injector.injectMembers()` method?

```
//I am calling this method in init method of my application
private static final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new A(), new B());

//Injecting dependencies using setters of all classes bound in modules A and B
injector.injectAllMembers()??
```

Comment: Could you give an code example of certaing use case?

Comment: Guice already does it. Are you actually having an issue?

Answer (score 14):

Why do you need to inject dependencies manually?

Guice injects dependencies into the fields and methods automatically.
Use:

```
YourClass yourClass = injector.getInstance(YourClass.class);
```

Guice documentation:

> Whenever Guice creates an instance, it
>   performs this injection automatically
>   (after first performing constructor
>   injection), so if you're able to let
>   Guice create all your objects for you,
>   you'll never need to use this method.

You need to inject members by yourself only into a manually created instance like this:

```
YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
injector.injectMembers(yourClass);
```

Or you can use something like that:

```
public class YourClassProvider implements Provider<YourClass> {

    private final Injector injector;

    @Inject
    public YourClassProvider(Injector injector) {
        this.injector = injector;
    }

    public YourClass get() {

        YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
        injector.injectMembers(yourClass);

        return yourClass;
    }
}
```

In any case, setters of YourClass should be annotated with @Inject.