# Roboguice injection into adapter

Tags: android, code-injection, roboguice

I have an adapter which extends `ArrayAdapter<T>` and want to inject into them `LayoutInflater`. Code presented below, but inflater is always `null`

```
public abstract class MyAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

    @Inject
    protected LayoutInflater inflater;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // inflater here is null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you've created `MyAdapter` instance with `new` instead of injecting it.

In this case I would not recommend to inject `LayoutInflater`, unless you want to use different implementations of this class, example mock of `LayoutInflater` for testing.

Obtain the instance in constructor:

```
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

It would be more efficient. I can't see any benefit from injecting `LayoutInflater`.
Dependency injection is ok, but don't use it when it's not necessary and slow.

Comment: Yes i create my adapter instance with `new` because i should to pass arguments into constructor. How i can inject it into activity? How i can choose requared constructor and pass params to it?

Comment: For passing args into constructor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237996/pass-parameter-to-constructor-with-guice
Or `injectMembers`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116383/guice-injectmembers-method
Both solutions are ugly in your case :)

Answer (score 5):

Inject dependencies in any class

```
 RoboGuice.getInjector(context).injectMembers(this);
```

use in constructor, just need context,
great works for me